# How to send variables from a .gs file to a .html file

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working with a web app. I have a button that activates a function in a .gs file that retrieves data (an array of numbers). I need to send this data over to the html to be displayed. I have tried returning the .gs function but that does not give an output.

Comment: Take a look at [templated html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) in the documentation. If you don't like templated html you can use the onReadyState event to get the data from the server using [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().functionName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) also in the documentation

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! please post this as an answer so I can mark this as answered for other people to see.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at templated html in the documentation. If you don't like templated html you can use the onReadyState event to get the data from the server using google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().functionName() also in the documentation – Cooper